# How to auto-fill fields on new form based on a lookup column of same list?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, javascript, office-365, lookup-column

I have a lookup column that lists the issue ids of the same list. Based on its selection, I need to pre-fill the fields on new form with the values of previously created issues (like issue category, function etc). How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Those fields should be available on the column lookup settings, you should be able to select the fields you want to display

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer with an example? I guess that would help me understand better.